# force set static ipv4 address to unlink interface in systemd-networkd

Tags: networking, router, systemd, static

I have configured static ipv4 address interface in systemd-network

5-lan.link

```
[Match]
MACAddress=80:ee:73:16:bf:33
[Link]
Description=Default lan adapter
Name=lan
```

10-lan.network

```
[Match]
Name=lan
[Network]
Address=192.168.1.1/24
```

Everything is fine, if link is up. But if interface cable plug off from switch, interface address is not set.

But if interface not set, isc dhcp-server and other network services with bind to local interface and failed to start too.

Old initV systemv configure and start static interfaces in any way, have or not these interfaces link up. How i have force systemd-networkd interface init interface in same way?

Or whats wrong with dependents in other network *.service units, where depend to these interface address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How i have force systemd-networkd interface init interface in same way?

```
[Network]
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
```